# Hash values different when comparing .NET to nodejs (crypto)

Tags: c#, node.js, hash

I'm getting different values when I attempt to hash the same password/salt combination in node and .NET.   (Yes, I know SHA1 is dangerous, I'm trying to change that too).

C#

```
byte[] unencodedBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
byte[] saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);

byte[] buffer = new byte[unencodedBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];

Buffer.BlockCopy(unencodedBytes, 0, buffer, 0, unencodedBytes.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(saltBytes, 0, buffer, unencodedBytes.Length - 1, saltBytes.Length);

byte[] hash = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1").ComputeHash(buffer);

//This is what I need
string hashedString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

Here's my JS

```
var buffer = [];
var unicodePassword = new Buffer(password, 'utf16le');
for (var i = 0; i < unicodePassword.length; ++i) {
     buffer.push(unicodePassword[i]);
}
var salt = new Buffer(userEntry.PasswordSalt, 'base64');
for (var i = 0; i < salt.length; i++) {
      buffer.push(salt[i]);
}
var bufferString = new Buffer(buffer);

//This is what I need
var hashedString = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(bufferString).digest('base64');
```

I know that I'm getting the exact same byte array in both implementations when I send it off to be hashed.   It looks like this code is doing the exact same thing but the value of `hashedString` is not the same.  Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Check the byte arrays of your `unencodedBytes` and `unicodePassword` to make sure they are EXACTLY the same. It appears that you are encoding your `String` in C# using Unicode, whereas in your JavaScript implementation, you're using `UTF16LE`. This will likely cause issues.

Comment: Damn you were right.  There was a extra 0 after the `unicodePassword` and a missing one after the salt, but the rest of the data is the same so I easily missed it.  What encoding should I use instead?  I guess I could just manually add/remove 0s.

Comment: I would recommend using UTF-8 on both ends if possible, should cover your bases pretty well. I assume you're using this for password authentication?

Comment: I can't do that because this is intended to be a one-way migration.  I have a bunch of users with existing passwords that I need to authenticate that first time before they have to change it.  I was unable to find an encoding that worked. `utf16le` was the closest i found

Comment: I see. So it looks like you're going to have to use `UTF-16LE (Little Endian)` on both ends. I'm not 100% sure if C# allows you to specify the `endianness` of it's UTF-16 encoding, but you'll want to choose `LE` if you get a chance. See if that fixes things.

Comment: Will manually add/removing the zeros (the same way) work every time? I suppose I could test it, but maybe you know offhand.

Comment: I would say no. Because the way [UTF-16 works, there are some technicalities to how characters are represented (two byte surrogate pairs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description). So, sometimes those bytes will be zeros, and sometimes they will not be (for example, extended Japanese characters will probably use these bytes.) It's better to simply standardize the encoding, then try to hack away at bytes and hope they come out equal.

Answer (score -1):

the default `Encoding.Unicode` is emitting byteOrderMask
What if you create Encoding without BOM in C# code?

`new UnicodeEncoding(false, false)`